# Libgdx + Box2d working with 2 cameras

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, box2d

Recently I have read that you can work with 2 cameras whenever you involve Box2d, which only works in meters.

In my Renderer class, I receive all the entities in the game and then draw them.
I work with `ashley` library so all my entities are a formed by components.

Now, in my renderer method I check if the current Entity has `BodyComponent`. If true, then it draws the Sprite in the `physicsCam`, who has a Viewport of meters. Otherwise, it will just draw the Sprite in sceneCam, which has a Viewport of pixels.

My problem is I try to draw the Sprite according to the Body's position in meters, but it is drawn not exactly where the body is.

NOTE: I also have `PhysicsDebugSystem` which basically just call the `DebugRenderer.render()` method.

Here is my RenderSystem class:

```
package engine.systems;

import com.badlogic.ashley.core.Component;
import com.badlogic.ashley.core.ComponentMapper;
import com.badlogic.ashley.core.Entity;
import com.badlogic.ashley.core.Family;
import com.badlogic.ashley.systems.IteratingSystem;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

import engine.Values;
import engine.components.BodyComponent;
import engine.components.SpriteComponent;
import engine.components.TransformComponent;

public class RenderSystem extends IteratingSystem{

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Array<Entity> renderQueue;
    private OrthographicCamera sceneCam;
    private OrthographicCamera physicsCam;
    private ComponentMapper<SpriteComponent> txt;
    private ComponentMapper<TransformComponent> trs;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public RenderSystem(SpriteBatch batch) {
        super(Family.all(TransformComponent.class, SpriteComponent.class).get());
        txt = ComponentMapper.getFor(SpriteComponent.class);
        trs = ComponentMapper.getFor(TransformComponent.class);
        sceneCam = new OrthographicCamera(Values.WIDTH, Values.HEIGHT);
        sceneCam.setToOrtho(false);
        physicsCam = new OrthographicCamera(Values.WIDTH, Values.HEIGHT);
        physicsCam.setToOrtho(false);
        renderQueue = new Array<Entity>();
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.update(deltaTime);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(230/255f, 242/255f, 242/255f, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        sceneCam.update();
        physicsCam.update();
        batch.enableBlending();
        batch.begin();
        for (Entity entity : renderQueue) {
            Component comp = entity.getComponent(BodyComponent.class);
            if(comp == null) {
                batch.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCam.combined);
            } else {
                batch.setProjectionMatrix(physicsCam.combined);
            }
            SpriteComponent texture = txt.get(entity);
            TransformComponent transform = trs.get(entity);
            if (texture.region == null || transform.isHidden) {
                continue;
            }
            texture.region.setPosition(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            texture.region.setRotation(transform.rotation);
            texture.region.setScale(transform.scale.x, transform.scale.y);
            texture.region.draw(batch);
        }
        batch.end();
        renderQueue.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        renderQueue.add(entity);
    }

    public OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
        return sceneCam;
    }

}
```

In my GameWorld class I construct the ball in this method:

```
public void initBall() {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        float x = Values.WIDTH/2*Values.PPM;
        float y = Values.HEIGHT*Values.PPM;
        SpriteComponent txt = new SpriteComponent();
        txt.region = skin.getSprite("soccerball");
        txt.region.setSize(Values.BALL_WIDTH, Values.BALL_HEIGHT);
        entity.add(txt);
        TransformComponent trs = new TransformComponent();
        trs.isHidden = false;
        trs.position.x = x;
        trs.position.y = y;
        entity.add(trs);
        BodyComponent bc = new BodyComponent();
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        // Set our body to dynamic
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        // Set our body's starting position in the world
        bodyDef.position.set(x, y+Values.BALL_HEIGHT/2);
        bc.body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        bc.body.applyAngularImpulse(50f, true);

        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.setRadius(Values.BALL_WIDTH/2f);
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = circle;
        fixtureDef.density = 20f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f;
        bc.body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        circle.dispose();
        entity.add(bc);
        engine.addEntity(entity);
    }
```

Here's the screenshot I took during the simulation:
[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/053cfa2.png]

Comment: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Comment: I read the article but I still don't understand what's wrong with my code. I use one camera for GUI and one camera for Physics world. Why is it still not working?

Comment: Just use one camera. There is nothing in that screenshot for which you should use banana units. Don't make things harder than it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your ball sprite seems to be rendered offset from your box2d body is because your texture's anchor is it's bottom left corner, which means that when you set your texture's position you basically set the position of it's bottom left corner. To properly position your ball you'll need to subtract it's half-width and half-height from it's position:

```
final float halfWidth = texture.region.getRegionWidth() * 0.5f;
final float halfHeight = texture.region.getRegionHeight() * 0.5f;
texture.region.setPosition(transform.position.x - halfWidth, transform.position.y - halfHeight);
```

I'll also urge you to [read this box2d blog post](http://box2d.org/2011/12/pixels/) since, from the code you posted, you don't seem to scale your box2d entites which means that that ball you have is `Values.BALL_WIDTH` METERS wide. Judging from the screenshot it looks like it's ~2.5m radius. That's one huge ball!